# AngularFireStorageModule Not found

Tags: firebase, ionic3, angularfire2

Im using angularfire2 for my ionic project.when i going to add AngularFireStorageModule to the app.module.ts its show there is no AngularFireStorageModule.this the version i use

> firebase": "^4.6.0, / angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.3
>
> @angular/core": "5.2.9

when i update it to the latest version this error occurs in terminal.after i import this its says unused import.

> import { app, auth, database, firestore, functions, messaging, storage
>   } from 'firebase/app';

older version works fine for me but only problem is it doesn't  import StorageModule.how to slove this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AngularFire didn't have AngularFireStorage until `5.0.0-rc.6`; you'll need to upgrade. See the release notes: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/releases